# How to answer questions with “vous êtes-vous” and “si” ?

Tags: grammaire, questions

How do I answer:

> *Vous êtes-vous trempé[e] avec les giboulées de mars ?*

Also:

> *Si je vais à Paris, irez-vous, si je reste ?*

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of the last sentence: "If I go to Paris, will you go, if I stay?" Do you mean, "if I stay here (instead of going to Paris)" or "if I stay in Paris"?

Comment: Both sentences sounds wrong

Comment: Literally you would said "Les giboulées de mars vous ont-elles trempé ?". I think it's gramatically correct, but it sounds weird... The second phrase would be "Viendras-tu avec moi si je vais à Paris ?" I don't know if that's what your looking for...

Comment: Welcome to French Language Lucy Rudolph. There are two entirely unrelated questions here, you're supposed to ask one at a time, that's how stackexchange sites work. Moreover you will get better answers if you show you have done a little research, for example here  what could say how you would answer those questions and we could the tell what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

The first is an example of a [reflexive verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_verb).

For example:

- Je me lave (I wash myself)
- Tu te laves
- Il se lave
- Nous nous lavons
- Vous vous lavez
- Ils se lavent

Swapping the order of the words to make a question (e.g. *Aimez-vous ?* instead of *Vous aimez.*) is how you get the question *Vous êtes-vous trempé ?*

A correct reply is, *Oui, je me suis trempé !* alternatively *Non, je ne me suis pas trempé.*

---

According to https://www.google.fr/search?q=si+pr%C3%A9sent+futur there are various ways to use "si" in a sentence; for example:

- To express a probability or near-certainty, *Si + présent de l'indicatif, futur simple*

  > Si vous y allez, j'irai aussi.
- To express a hypothesis, *Si + imparfait, conditionnel présent*

  > Si vous y alliez, j'irais aussi.

Comment: La dernière phrase me semble mauvaise, ça devrait être un futur : si vous y allez, j'irai aussi. Pour le conditionnel, il faudrait : si vous y alliez, j'irais aussi.

Comment: Est-il permis d'utiliser un futur sans conditionnel, après "si"?

Comment: Cherchez si+présent+futur dans google, il y a des explications claires de la règle.

Answer (score 0):

> Vous êtes-vous trempé[e] avec les giboulées de mars ? (x)

The most usual expression related to rain with such a verb is not *se tremper* imho but rather [*se faire tremper*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tremper) (see [also](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/se-faire-tremper?)):

> *Se faire tremper*. Être complètement mouillé. *Des averses tombaient sans relâche, tout Bonneville se faisait tremper pour voir enfoncer
>   les pieux à l'aide d'un pilon* (Zola, Joie de vivre, 1884, p. 908).
>   *La pluie tombait avec plus de force. « Pourvu qu'elle ne tarde pas: elle se ferait tremper en venant ici. »* (Arland, Ordre, 1929, p. 73).

It's also possible to soak your clothes in water basically(*tremper ses vêtements*) but not in/with a storm. Otherwise something(like rain) might also do this *to* you/your clothes, as alluded to in the comments:

> *Nous fûmes rafraîchis par le vent, chauffés par le soleil, la pluie nous trempa jusqu'au dernier fil, la sueur jusqu'au dernier poil*
>   (Flaub., Champs et grèves, 1848, p. 304)

You may even encounter an *adjectif déverbal* such as *trempe* from *trempé* i.e. *tu es complètement trempe*. So the question, and answer, could have been:

> Q. Vous êtes-vous fait tremper par les giboulées de mars ?
>
> A1. Oui, je me suis fait tremper à plus d'une reprise...
>
> A2. Non, je ne me suis pas fait tremper car j'ai toujours mon parapluie à
>   portée de main.

Asking about a transient state in relation to an extended period of time feels unnatural imho. Exploring something like *getting caught* by the storm would maybe yield more interesting results (such as *prendre une averse*, ou *se faire prendre par la pluie* etc.).

---

> Si je vais à Paris, (y) irez-vous, si j'y reste ?
>
> Si j'allais à Paris, (y) iriez-vous, si j'y restais ?

The question was incorrect because the pronoun *y* used as *complément adverbial* is required here, technically twice(to go where and to stay where... *y* i.e. Paris).

But there is a specific rule (discussed in Le Bon Usage(*Grevisse*) @659 e 3-, ex.: *S'il faut que tu ailles à Paris, tu iras!*, Sand, Correspondance, 5 avril 1847) whereby the *y* is removed in front of both the conditionnel or future tense of the verb *to go* (*aller*). Otherwise you would have to reply *j'y irai/j'y irais* with the examples provided in the other [answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/12517)(see also [this](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/n2/cdm2.htm) and [this](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/expression-de-lhypothese-et-de-la-condition.html) for *si* contructs generally). This is useful because if you were asked "Y vas-tu?", you would have to answer either "Je vais à Paris(avec vous)" or "J'y vais"(and not *je vais*, since this is the present tense and you cannot do without the *y* there.).